# Stop ServiceStack Metadata Auto Redirect

Tags: web-services, servicestack

Since I have upgraded to the new ServiceStack 4.0.48 from a very old version, it automatically redirects me to the `/metadata` page. How do I disable that?

I have added the ServiceStack Application to host off an existing application, now I can't use my existing application because it keeps redirecting to `/metadata`.

I had a look online but can't really find anything, It never used to automatically redirect.

I need to go to example.com but it keeps redirecting me to example.com/metadata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to display a homepage, it needs a default index page, e.g. `default.cshtml` or `default.html`. If there isn't a home page ServiceStack automatically redirects to the `/metadata` page so it has something to show. If you have a default document that isn't getting displayed, it maybe due to an Exception on StartUp resulting in incomplete configuration - you can check for Start up errors with the `?debug=requestinfo` [Debug Route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info).

Otherwise to redirect to a different route for the home page you can use:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    DefaultRedirectPath = "/alt-path"
});
```

Whilst the Metadata redirects can be changed with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    MetadataRedirectPath = "/alt-path"
});
```

Comment: I have a Default.aspx  page, and getting an error about too many redirects.

Comment: Is it even possible to have an ASP.Net Web forms application hosted with ServiceStack being initialized from its global.ascx?

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk The `default.aspx` is an ASP.NET WebForms page that's not handled by ServiceStack. You'd need to [host ServiceStack at a /custom-path](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework) to have it work side-by-side with an existing web framework.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that and was exactly that what I was trying to find now A+